# AngularJS component doesn't appear in the View

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am following the AngularJS tutorial and I don't understand how they link component to the view. I made a very similar component:

```
angular.module('phonecatApp').component('nameList', {
    template:
            '<p ng-repeat="name in $ctrl.names>' +
            '{{names.name}}' +
            '<p>Total number of phones: {{$ctrl.names.length}}</p>' +
            '</p>',
    controller: function NameListController(){
        this.names = [
            {
                name:'BOB'
            }, {
               name:'Rob' 
            }, {
               name:"Nob"
            }
        ];
    }
});
```

Which is really similar to:

```
angular.module('phonecatApp').component('phoneList',{
    template:
            '<ul>'+
                '<li ng-repeat="phone in $ctrl.phones">' +
                    '<span>{{phone.name}}</span>' +
                    '<p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>' +
                '</li>' +
            '</ul>',
    controller: function PhoneListController() {
        this.phones = [
            {
              name: 'Nexus S',
              snippet: 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'
            }, {
              name: 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
              snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
            }, {
              name: 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
              snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
            }
        ];
    }
});
```

But in index.html I can't get my component to show.

```
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="phone-list.component.js"></script>
    <script src="name-list.component.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

  <!-- Use a custom component to render a list of phones -->
  <phone-list></phone-list>
  <name-list></name-list>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you add `ng-app="phonecatApp"` to `<body>` (or some other parent node)?

Comment: what does your module declaration look like in app.js? you need `angular.module('phonecatApp', [])` before the component definition.

Comment: Yes I have added 'angular.module('phonecatApp', [])' to app.js which is linked in index.html

Comment: @therobinkim I just added it but even if that was the case why did the phone list come up but not the name-list?

Comment: @BobbyBaboon Did your phone list appear before you put `ng-app`, or did it only appear after you put `ng-app`?

Comment: @therobinkim it worked when I put {{name.name}} into a <li ng-repeat="name in $ctrl.names">

Answer (score 0):

Please correct this line of code and test it again.

```
'{{name.name}}' +
```

Copy this!

```
angular.module('phonecatApp').component('nameList', {
    template:
            '<p ng-repeat="name in $ctrl.names>' +
            '{{name.name}}' +
            '<p>Total number of phones: {{$ctrl.names.length}}</p>' +
            '</p>',
    controller: function NameListController(){
        this.names = [
            {
                name:'BOB'
            }, {
               name:'Rob' 
            }, {
               name:"Nob"
            }
        ];
    }
});
```

Comment: That still doesn't work. It is not showing up in the view still.